# ACL Joomla Permissions of different users for different categories and articles

Tags: acl, joomla-3.9

Where exactly do I have to set so that only this one category and article are visible to the user in Access Control List?

I was able to set that the rest of the content is not edited by a user who does not have access to it.

The point is, however, that he also does not see them in the administration panel. Is it possible?

https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Access_Control_List_Tutorial

[image: ACL VIEW HIDE ARTICLE CATEGORY]